# AerospikeSin connector task is in failed state

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, aerospike

Below is Error:

{
"name": "aerospike-userprofile-sink",
"connector": {
"state": "RUNNING",
"worker_id": "192.168.29.43:8083"
},
"tasks": [
{
"id": 0,
"state": "FAILED",
"worker_id": "192.168.29.43:8083",
"trace": "com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:\n\n1) [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library\n  at AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikePolicy(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:83)\n      \_ installed by: KafkaInboundModule -> AerospikeGuiceModule\n  at AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikeClient(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:60)\n      \_ for 1st parameter\n  at AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikeClient(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:60)\n      \_ installed by: KafkaInboundModule -> AerospikeGuiceModule\n  while locating AsyncAerospikeClient\n\nLearn more:\n  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_IN_CUSTOM_PROVIDER\n\n1 error\n\n======================\nFull classname legend:\n======================\nAerospikeGuiceModule: "com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule"\nAsyncAerospikeClient: "com.aerospike.connect.aerospike.AsyncAerospikeClient"\nKafkaInboundModule:   "com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.KafkaInboundModule"\n========================\nEnd of classname legend:\n========================\n\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:251)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1104)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inbound.aerospike.AerospikeService.isFeatureEnabled(AerospikeService.kt:117)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.AerospikeSinkTask.verifyFeatureEnabled(AerospikeSinkTask.kt:160)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.AerospikeSinkTask.start(AerospikeSinkTask.kt:153)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:312)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.ensureAvailability(Epoll.java:81)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.(EpollEventLoop.java:56)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:186)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:37)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:114)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:101)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:78)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:54)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.aerospike.config.AerospikeClientConfig.getAsyncAerospikePolicy(AerospikeClientConfig.kt:197)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.aerospike.config.AerospikeClientConfig.getAsyncAerospikePolicy$default(AerospikeClientConfig.kt:186)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikePolicy(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:83)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule$$FastClassByGuice$$3256232.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE()\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule$$FastClassByGuice$$3256232.apply()\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:260)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:40)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:60)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1101)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.(Epoll.java:40)\n\t... 43 more\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only supported on Linux\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:317)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.(Native.java:85)\n\t... 44 more\n"
}
],
"type": "sink"
}

Have places the aerospike-sink connector jar in libs folder of kafka

And Following are procedure im following

1. Running kafka connect : bin/connect-ditributed.sh config/aerospike-sink.properties

For creating connector:
curl --location 'http://localhost:8083/connectors' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{
"name": "aerospike-userprofile-sink",
"config": {
"connector.class": "com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.AerospikeSinkConnector",
"config-file":"/Users/b0276929/Downloads/kafka_2.12-3.2.3/aerospike-config/aerospike-kafka-inbound.yml",
"tasks.max": "1",
"namespace": "disk_Dialer",
"set": "USER_PROFILE",
"key-field":"uid",
"ttl": -1,
"topics": "users"
}
}'

aerospike-kafka-inbound.yml

max-queued-records: 32768

aerospike:
seeds:
- localhost:
port: 3000
tls-name: red

## - 192.168.50.2

topics:
users:
invalid-record: ignore
mapping:
namespace:
mode: static
value: disk_Dialer
set:
mode: static
value: USER_PROFILE
key-field:
source: value-field
field-name: uid
ttl:
mode: static
value: -1
bins: # Aerospike record bins config.
type: multi-bins
all-value-fields: true

Below is Error

{
"name": "aerospike-userprofile-sink",
"connector": {
"state": "RUNNING",
"worker_id": "192.168.29.43:8083"
},
"tasks": [
{
"id": 0,
"state": "FAILED",
"worker_id": "192.168.29.43:8083",
"trace": "com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:\n\n1) [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library\n  at AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikePolicy(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:83)\n      \_ installed by: KafkaInboundModule -> AerospikeGuiceModule\n  at AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikeClient(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:60)\n      \_ for 1st parameter\n  at AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikeClient(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:60)\n      \_ installed by: KafkaInboundModule -> AerospikeGuiceModule\n  while locating AsyncAerospikeClient\n\nLearn more:\n  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_IN_CUSTOM_PROVIDER\n\n1 error\n\n======================\nFull classname legend:\n======================\nAerospikeGuiceModule: "com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule"\nAsyncAerospikeClient: "com.aerospike.connect.aerospike.AsyncAerospikeClient"\nKafkaInboundModule:   "com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.KafkaInboundModule"\n========================\nEnd of classname legend:\n========================\n\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:251)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1104)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inbound.aerospike.AerospikeService.isFeatureEnabled(AerospikeService.kt:117)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.AerospikeSinkTask.verifyFeatureEnabled(AerospikeSinkTask.kt:160)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.AerospikeSinkTask.start(AerospikeSinkTask.kt:153)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:312)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.ensureAvailability(Epoll.java:81)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.(EpollEventLoop.java:56)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:186)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:37)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:114)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:101)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:78)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:54)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.aerospike.config.AerospikeClientConfig.getAsyncAerospikePolicy(AerospikeClientConfig.kt:197)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.aerospike.config.AerospikeClientConfig.getAsyncAerospikePolicy$default(AerospikeClientConfig.kt:186)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule.getAsyncAerospikePolicy(AerospikeGuiceModule.kt:83)\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule$$FastClassByGuice$$3256232.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE()\n\tat com.aerospike.connect.inject.AerospikeGuiceModule$$FastClassByGuice$$3256232.apply()\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:260)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:40)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:60)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)\n\tat com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1101)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.(Epoll.java:40)\n\t... 43 more\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only supported on Linux\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:317)\n\tat com.aerospike.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.(Native.java:85)\n\t... 44 more\n"
}
],
"type": "sink"
}

Have places the aerospike-sink connector jar in libs folder of kafka

And Following are procedure im following

1. Running kafka connect : bin/connect-ditributed.sh config/aerospike-sink.properties

For creating connector:
curl --location 'http://localhost:8083/connectors' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{
"name": "aerospike-userprofile-sink",
"config": {
"connector.class": "com.aerospike.connect.kafka.inbound.AerospikeSinkConnector",
"config-file":"/Users/b0276929/Downloads/kafka_2.12-3.2.3/aerospike-config/aerospike-kafka-inbound.yml",
"tasks.max": "1",
"namespace": "disk_Dialer",
"set": "USER_PROFILE",
"key-field":"uid",
"ttl": -1,
"topics": "users"
}
}'

aerospike-kafka-inbound.yml

max-queued-records: 32768

aerospike:
seeds:
- localhost:
port: 3000
tls-name: red

## - 192.168.50.2

topics:
users:
invalid-record: ignore
mapping:
namespace:
mode: static
value: disk_Dialer
set:
mode: static
value: USER_PROFILE
key-field:
source: value-field
field-name: uid
ttl:
mode: static
value: -1
bins: # Aerospike record bins config.
type: multi-bins
all-value-fields: true